# 'Class' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I've had a look at the other threads answers that have a very similar question to mine, but I can't seem to get it working.

```
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        Container = tk.Frame(self)
        Container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        Container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        Container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Login, Admin):
            PageName = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=Container, controller=self)
            self.frames[PageName] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self, PageName):
        frame = self.franes[PageName]
        frame.tkraise()


class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(self, parent) (...)
```

I was following another threads answer with this code in order to switch between frames.

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'Login' object has no attribute 'tk'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Jake/Google Drive/StockControl/Framework/src/Login.py", line 70, in <module>
    App = Application()
  File "G:/Jake/Google Drive/StockControl/Framework/src/Login.py", line 15, in __init__
    frame = F(parent=Container, controller=self)
  File "G:/Jake/Google Drive/StockControl/Framework/src/Login.py", line 28, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, parent)
  File "C:\Utilities\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2738, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Utilities\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2286, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Utilities\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2256, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'Login' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you! (Python 3.6)

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: Because it doesnt. `tk` is a module, and `tk.Frame` which you are inheriting from doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: It doesn't specify the line I'm getting the error from. @Daniel

Comment: @BłażejMichalik Okay I think I understand.

Comment: @Jake: python always displays the line. What is the full traceback?

Comment: @Daniel, editted post. Sorry thought you meant line within the same file rather than the modules. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `super` in Python 3, the `self` argument is automatically prepended as the first argument; your definition should look like this:

```
class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
```